# problemas con div oculto

Tags: php, css, php7, div, display

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo un formulario de edición de datos donde tengo un campo que cuando el valor == ERRÓNEA me muestra otro SELECT con una serie de valores. Todo funciona bien hasta que lo mantengo oculto con `style="display: none"`. En ese momento cuando lo muestro el select me salta de línea.
El código funciona bien a excepción de ese "problema". adjunto captura del form.
Este es el código:

```
                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 rojo">TIPO LLAMADA:</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <select name="TIPOLLAMADA" class="form-control" id="TIPOLLAMADA" onchange="verErronea()" required>
                                            <option value="">Elija un tipo llamada</option>
                                            <?php
                                            foreach ($db->query($sqlTipoLlamadas) as $sqlTipoLlamada) {
                                                if ($row['TIPOLLAMADA'] == $sqlTipoLlamada['TIPOLLAMADA']) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option selected value="<?= $sqlTipoLlamada['TIPOLLAMADA']; ?>"><?= $sqlTipoLlamada['TIPOLLAMADA']; ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                } else {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?= $sqlTipoLlamada['TIPOLLAMADA'] ?>"><?= $sqlTipoLlamada['TIPOLLAMADA'] ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Si es tipo de errónea mostramos datos -->
                                <div class="row" id="divERRONEA" name="divERRONEA" style="display: none;border-radius: 5px;padding: 5px;">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 rojo">TIPO ERRÓNEA:</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-9">
                                        <select name="ERRONEA" class="form-control" id="ERRONEA">
                                            <option value="">Elija un tipo de error</option>
                                            <?php
                                            foreach ($db->query($sqlErrores) as $Error) {
                                                if ($row['ERRONEA'] == $Error['descripcion']) {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option selected value="<?= $row['ERRONEA']; ?>" selected><?= $row['ERRONEA']; ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                } else {
                                                    ?>
                                                    <option value="<?= $Error['descripcion'] ?>"><?= $Error['descripcion'] ?></option>
                                                <?php
                                                }
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!-- fin mostrar tipo de errónea -->
```

Comment: Deberías agregar tu código y explicar mejor tu duda

Comment: Hola Noe, aun no has adjuntado el codigo, o captura que mencionas. Te recomiendo compartir el codigo relacionado con el problema, una captura puede servir para entender el contexto visual de lo que explicas, pero el codigo sera lo que ayude a solucionarlo

Comment: perdón no le había dado a subir a la imagen...

Answer (score 0):

1. te recomiendo no usar inline javascript ya que es una mala practica. (*onchange="verErronea()"*)
2. usa este codigo jquery:

```js
    $("#TIPOLLAMADA").change(function(){
    

    if($(this).val() == "NOMBRE_DEL_VALUE_ERRONEO"){
    $("#divERRONEA").show();
    }
    else{
    $("#divERRONEA").hide();
    }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="TIPOLLAMADA">
<option>etc</option>
<option>etc</option>
<option value="NOMBRE_DEL_VALUE_ERRONEO">ERRONEO</option>
</select>

<div id="divERRONEA" style="display:none">

ACA MOSTRAMOS TODO SI SE SELECCIONÓ ERRONEO
</div>
```

reemplaza ***NOMBRE_DEL_VALUE_ERRONEO*** por el valor de el option "ERRONEO"

Comment: Mil gracias @IntruzO, funcionar me funciona bien tan solo es que al mostrar ese div, no me lo muestra de la misma forma que si le quito el display: none